# How can I read this mathematical sentence in English?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am studying Set Theory and just run accross this sentences:

```
+: NxN → N
-: NxN → N
```

But I have no clues on how to read them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These define ($:$) the operators ($+$) and ($-$), both of which take pairs of natural numbers (elements of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$) to natural numbers ($\mathbb{N}$). This notation is often used to define an function/map from the domain, here $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, to ($\to$) the codomain, here $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: For example: +(1,2) = 3

Comment: The notation doesn't really _define_ the addition and subtraction operators. It just _asserts_ that each of them takes two natural numbers and produce a single natural number.

Comment: @HenningMakholm True, but I suspect the usual definitions come in the next couple of sentences of the text.

Comment: Great! The answer and comments made it quite clear about the usage and meaning of the sentence. Thanks!